# Sql-Get time ranges from million+ rows for particular condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, gaps-and-islands

I am working with SQL Server 2012, I have a table with approx 35 column and 10+ million rows. 
I need to find time ranges from across the data where the value of any particular column is matching 
E.g.
The sample data is as below

```
 Datetime        col1  col2  col3
2018-05-31 0:00     1   2   1 
2018-05-31 13:00    2   2   2
2018-05-31 14:30    3   2   1
2018-05-31 15:00    4   3   1
2018-05-31 16:00    4   5   1
2018-05-31 17:00    3   2   2
2018-05-31 17:30    3   2   4
2018-05-31 18:00    2   2   4
2018-05-31 20:00    1   2   6
2018-05-31 21:00    2   2   3
2018-05-31 21:10    2   2   1
2018-05-31 22:00    1   6   3
2018-05-31 22:00    4   5   1
2018-05-31 23:59    4   7   2
```

Find the time range from data where col2 value =< 2, accordingly my expected result set is as below

```
Start Time           End time           Time Diff
2018-05-31 0:00     2018-05-31 14:30    14:30:00
2018-05-31 17:00    2018-05-31 21:10    4:10:00
```

I can achieved the same with below logic, but it's extremely slow
I get all rows and then

1. Order by date_Time
2. Scan the rows get the first row where exactly value is matching and record that timestamp as start time.
3. Scan further rows till i get the row where condition is  breaking and record that timestamp as end time.

But as i have to play with huge no. Of rows, overall this will make my operation slow, any inputs or pseudo code to improve the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a slightly modified difference in row number method here.  The purpose of the first CTE labelled `cte1` is to add a computed column which labels islands we want, having a `col2` values <= 2, as 1 and everything else as 0.  Then, we can compute the difference of two row numbers, and aggregate over the islands to find the starting and ending times, and the difference between those times.

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT *,
        CASE WHEN col2 <= 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS class
    FROM yourTable
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Datetime) -
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY class ORDER BY Datetime) rn
    FROM cte1
)

SELECT
    MIN(Datetime) AS [Start Time],
    MAX(Datetime) AS [End Time],
    CONVERT(TIME, MAX(Datetime) - MIN(Datetime)) AS [Time Diff]
FROM cte2
WHERE class = 1
GROUP BY rn
ORDER BY MIN(Datetime);
```

[image]

### Demo